# NTLM Authentication in a WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, ntlm

I am trying to load a URL which will show a image in a `WebView`.
I need to pass the credentials (username & password) before loading the URL.

Here, the URL is hosted from a server which has NTLM authentication.

I am able to hit another such URL and get the data. But how do I do the same stuff for a `WebView` in Android?

Comment: Can you please mark the answer by clicking on that tick at left of it?

Answer (score 4):

### You can use the [Chilkat Library](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/) for NTLM authentication.

1. download the java classes (contained in the zip/rar file from the downloads section)
   and add the package to the /src folder. the package name is com.chilkatsoft
2. add the libraries to the /libs folder. 
   the chilkat libraries folder are:

   - armeabi
   - armeabi-v7a
   - mips
   - x86

     ```
     public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         boolean success;
         success = http.UnlockComponent("anything");
         if (success != true) {
             return;
         }

         http.put_Login("<Username>");
         http.put_Password("<Password>");
         http.put_NtlmAuth(true);
         http.put_SessionLogFilename("ntlmAuthLog.txt");
         String html;
         html = http.quickGetStr("http://websitewithntlmnauthentication.com");
         //load the data to a webview from the string "html".
         webView.loadUrl(html,"","UTF-8"); }
     ```

     and add this after the `onCreate()`:

     ```
     static {
               // Important: Make sure the name passed to loadLibrary matches the shared library
               // found in your project's libs/armeabi directory.
               //  for "libchilkat.so", pass "chilkat" to loadLibrary
               //  for "libchilkatemail.so", pass "chilkatemail" to loadLibrary
               //  etc.
               // 
               System.loadLibrary("chilkat");

               // Note: If the incorrect library name is passed to System.loadLibrary,
               // then you will see the following error message at application startup:
               //"The application <your-application-name> has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again."
           }
     ```

Comment: Thanks. Chilkat library works great. For anyone looking for a sample code, can take a look here http://www.example-code.com/android/http_authentication.asp

Comment: @Sufian you can mark it as correct so everyone can see it

Comment: I would if I could. SO moderators need to have this right to mark a question as correct, Microsoft threads have this useful feature. :)

Comment: I found that this library is same as downloading the webpage page and displaying it in `WebView` the HTML. I wanted to run a Web App behind NTLM which enables a user to edit their document files, but this doesn't help that or from what I understand. Nonetheless, this should be marked as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The questions has: " I need to pass the credentials (username & password) before loading the URL." But, passing credentials before url is loaded is not a good practice.

There is no need for any third party library. It can be achieved by overriding the following method in WebViewClient:

```
        @Override
        public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view,
                HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm)
        {
            Log.d(TAG + "_onReceivedHttpAuthRequest", "host = " + host + " realm = " + realm);
//Show dialog and accept credentials from end-user. Hard-coding username and password is strict NO as it can be easlity reverse engineered.
            handler.proceed("username", "password");
        }
```