# NTLM authentication in WebView without providing password explicitly

Tags: android, authentication, android-webview, ntlm

I'm wondering if it is possible to access a Windows Authentication web service from an Android client without the Android app having access to the user's password.

For example, the Chrome Android app prompts for username/password when trying to access a site using NTLM Auth. I would like this same behavior without having to write a custom popup. Ideally, the Android WebView class would ask for the user credentials, but it seems like a custom WebViewClient is required for this behavior.

Maybe there's something I'm missing in the documentation, or there is another method of doing this that would pass credentials directly to IIS without using my Android app as a middleman. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NTLM Authentication in a webview Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934027/ntlm-authentication-in-a-webview-android)

Comment: Were you able to solve it?